# cbind throwing error in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe of dimensions`[1]  1 11` and `[1]  3 29`. I am trying to cbind these two dataframes such that dataframe having one row will be copied thrice to the resultant dataframe.

When I use cbind, it works sometimes but throws error as

> Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 3

```
> dim(a)
[1]  1 11
> dim (b)
[1]  3 29
> cbind(a,b)
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 3
```

However if I try subsetting, it works.

```
> cbind(a[1:10],b)  #Works Fine
> cbind(a[1:11],b) #Throws Error
```

Note: It works sometimes, but doesn't work if I run the code again.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Please refer `[cbind]` [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/cbind.html)

> If there are several matrix arguments, they must all have the same
>   number of columns (or rows) and this will be the number of columns (or
>   rows) of the result.

The resultant row will be equal to the row number of a and b.

Answer (score 2):

If you make them data tables then you do not have the error anymore.

```
cbind(iris[1:10, 1], iris[ 1:11,2:3]) # error

cbind(iris[1:10, 1], iris[ 1:11,2]) # warning message, missing values are copied
cbind(iris[1:10, 1], iris[ 1:11,2:3] %>% as.data.table()) # same
cbind(iris[1:10, 1] %>% as.data.table(), iris[ 1:11,2:3] )# same
      . Sepal.Width Petal.Length
 1: 5.1         3.5          1.4
 2: 4.9         3.0          1.4
 3: 4.7         3.2          1.3
 4: 4.6         3.1          1.5
 5: 5.0         3.6          1.4
 6: 5.4         3.9          1.7
 7: 4.6         3.4          1.4
 8: 5.0         3.4          1.5
 9: 4.4         2.9          1.4
10: 4.9         3.1          1.5
11: 5.1         3.7          1.5


# you can also make the extra values as zero or NA etc
temp <- iris[1:10,1] %>% as.data.table()
temp <- temp[match(rownames(iris[ 1:11,2:3]), rownames(temp[1:10, 1]))] 
# temp[is.na(temp)] <- ""
cbind(temp %>% as.data.table(), iris[ 1:11,2:3] )

      . Sepal.Width Petal.Length
 1: 5.1         3.5          1.4
 2: 4.9         3.0          1.4
 3: 4.7         3.2          1.3
 4: 4.6         3.1          1.5
 5: 5.0         3.6          1.4
 6: 5.4         3.9          1.7
 7: 4.6         3.4          1.4
 8: 5.0         3.4          1.5
 9: 4.4         2.9          1.4
10: 4.9         3.1          1.5
11:  NA         3.7          1.5
```